# Grails Forward param list

Tags: grails, controller

In my forward method, I need to have a param that is list:

```
forward(params:[selectedLicences:[1,2,3]]],action...)
```

Currently, when the same parameters are submitted through a form, I access them like this:

```
List<Long> licenses =  params.list("selectedLicences").collect{it as Long}
```

Is it possible to use the same code when forwarding, or I need to have code that will process the resulting String `[1,2,3]` and change it into a list?

I have seen one solution is to use the flash storage, but I am looking for other alternatives as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find a way to do it, so I am forwarding a list, which turns to string, and then I parse it back to list on receiving controller.. I am not working with large data (usually 2-3 values) so performance is not an issue in this case..